# Program keeps closing after execution via PHP. What to do?

Tags: php, exec, external, wampserver

First of all, i would like to ask you for patience, since i'm stil new to PHP and programming. Anyways, i need to open an external program via PHP script. For that i'm using the *exec* function. The problem is that this specific program i need to execute keeps closing after 1-3 seconds after the PHP script's execution. And i really don't know why's that happening.

At first i thought it was something with my script, but i've tried to execute another program, and the other one haven't closed unless i've closed the browser, even if the other program is made by the same developer.

I don't know if that might be useful but, my machine's OS is a Windows Server 2012 r2, and i'm using Wampserver 3.0.

What i've tried so far:

- I've tried to change the memory_limit to -1 (no limit) in the php.ini
- I've tried to change the max_post_size parameter from 6M to 60M in php.ini

Can anyone help me?
Btw, don't mind if my code ain't good. I'm learning by myself and i'm looking to improve. If you guys can give me some tips to improve my coding, i'll appreciate! :)

Thanks in advance, friends!

Code:

```
<?php

$cmd = exec('"<program directory path>"');
echo $cmd;
header ("Location: <HTML page>");
exit(); 
$output = shell_exec('type <program log after execution>');
echo "<pre>" . $output . "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Is there anything in your error log? (Possibly in C:\wamp\logs)

Comment: uh, `shell_exec('type ...`? That is UTTERLY unecessary. YOu don't have to fire up a shell to merely dump out the contents of a file. PHP can do that perfectly well itself, e.g `readfile()`

Comment: @MarcB, thanks for the heads up! I'll update my code right away!

Comment: @TecBrat, nope. It doesn't say anything in neither of the four Wampserver's logs.

Comment: It might be useful to know what program you are trying to launch

Comment: @RiggsFolly. Thanks for replying, mate! I'm trying to run a CFD software, and operate it through a PHP script. I already know how to do the second part. However the CFD software i'm using keeps closing after 2 seconds of the PHP script execution. And i want to choose when the application will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you expect your script to do, however I see several problems there.

The first problem is that you try to send a location header (with `header()`) **after** you potentially echoed some data. This will not work, because headers usually need to be sent before any output.

Second problem is the unconditional `exit()` in the middle of your script. [exit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) terminates the current script. Immediately. That means that anything below that line will **never** be executed. That is, you won't see the output of `shell_exec()`, and `shell_exec()` won't even run.

Comment: Hello, friend! Thanks for answering. I thought it was that, but the problem is, even after i commented these lines, and the problem still there. It was the first changed i did in my code.

Comment: I've just deleted the whole code, except the exec code. The problem still persists. =(